# SDE Jump-Diffusion

Tags: sde, jump-diffusion

If you combine the compound Poisson process with the Brownian motion you obtain the simplest case
of a Jump-diffusion. Let’s define
$$X_t = \mu t + \sigma W_t + J_t$$
where $W_t$ is a Wiener process and $J_t$ is a compound Poisson process. In what sense is possible to write an SDE to represent the dynamics of $X_t$? what is the meaning of $dJ_t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$dJ_{t}$ can be understood as a Steljes measure , when you want to define jumps using bounded variation function , but you can simply understand it as $J_{t}-J_{t-}$

Those processes belong to a more general class of process called [Levy processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process) through Lévy–Khintchine representation where you can define clearly the jump part, you can find better expanding of Ito's formula and exponential form based on Doleans-Dade forumula.

There are also more complex jumps models like [Bates model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_volatility_jump) or [double exponential Kou model](https://www.rocq.inria.fr/mathfi/Premia/free-version/doc/premia-doc/pdf_html/ap_kou_doc/index.html)

Comment: Hello @Kupoc allahoui. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$ J_t = \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} Z_i$$ be a [compound Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_process), with $(T_n)_{n\geq 1}$ being the jump times for Poisson process $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ and $(Z_i)_{i\geq 1}$ sequence of i.i.d. variables independent of $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$.

We need the stochastic integral against $dJ_t$ in order to make sense of $dJ_t$.

For discrete jump size we have
$$\delta J_t = J_t-J_{t^-} = Z_{N_t}(N_t - N_{t^-}) = Z_{N_t}\delta N_t$$

Then for a process $(u_s)_{s\geq 0}$  we have:

$$ \int_0^t u_s dJ_s  = \int_0^t u_s Z_{N_s}dN_s = \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} u_{T_i} Z_i$$

In particular, for $u$ set to constant $1$, we have:

$$ \int_0^t dJ_s =  J_t$$